# How to start and stop the Apple's Swift based productive server (program written by me) on Ubuntu?

Tags: services

I am currently developing a chat program where the Server as Ubuntu + Swift and client as JavaScript + WebSocket. Finally I reached the 0.1 version and I need to deploy it for public use.

I am renting a Virtual Cloud Server with Ubuntu 16.04 LST and I installed Swift 3 and my developed chat server as collection of `.swift` files. I can compile and run my chat server using swift commands. But as soon as I close my SSH connection the server stops. Yea, I can understand why.

1. How can I start my chat server permanently on my Virtual Cloud Server?
2. Do I really need to make it as a service e.g. `service squid start` then how?

Where to start? I searched a lot in internet but could not find any example or advice. Any help? Thank you in advance.